# gnome--terminal -e option not executing?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

I want to open my terminal with some commnads executed in it on bootup. So I wrote a script with following line in it:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "MyPC" -e "sh -c 'firefox &;exec bash'" --tab -t "MYPC2" -e "sh -c 'ls;exec bash'"
```

In this `firefox &` is not executing, however if I write only `firefox` it executes.
So only the second tab is opening not the first one

I know it's some spacing issue. If I write just `ls` that also executes.

What is the correct syntax?? Why is it not taking spacing??

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand-backgrounding method didn't seem to work as expected. I switched to `setsid` instead and it seems to work.

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "MyPC" -e "sh -c 'setsid firefox;bash'" --tab -t "MYPC2" -e "sh -c 'ls;bash'"
```

Also, you only need `bash`, not `exec bash`.

Comment: For others who come to the post: It worked after I removed the `;` after `&`. `"sh -c 'firefox & bash` For explanation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174296/92072